# MSI installer, Wix and dialog size value

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I've noticed that the articles, tutorials and samples of creating the custom dialogs in Wix always use the same dialog size - Width="370" Height="270"(in the installer units) which corresponds to 494px * 360px for 96DPI. The example is http://blogs.technet.com/b/alexshev/archive/2008/10/16/from-msi-to-wix-part-20-user-interface-required-dialog-boxes.aspx
Moreover, a lot of MSI installers use exactly this size for the dialogs. I wonder where this size value came from? Is there any guideline about the installer dialog size?

Answer (score 1):

These standard values for MSI UI dialogs come from Windows SDK, the `uisample.msi` file.

This size is close to the standard wizard Wizard interface, and MSI “Wizards” mimic Wizard '97 UI. See [Wizard '97 sample image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774544.aspx#wiz97Exterior), the size of the image is 513 × 397 px.

Answer (score 0):

If there's anything special about it, it likely hails from a size that looked good on a default Windows 95 or so taskbar configuration with a screen resolution of 640x480 pixels. Realistically you can use other sizes, such as Visual Studio's installation which is much larger.

Comment: I don't think that what you said makes much sense. Visual Studio installer does not use the windows installer UI(see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233642/how-do-you-make-a-really-nice-installer-like-visual-studios), so it can use arbitrary size. But my question IS about windows installer UI.

Comment: Also, I would like to notice that Wix has the built-in dialogs set(http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/WixUI_customizations.htm) and they use the mentioned size value as well and it is not customizable.

Comment: I've never customized a WiX UI, so sorry if customizing its size is hard. I thought your question was more about size than the underlying technology, hence the comment about Visual Studio's larger UI - it is indeed an external UI, but it is an installer.