# Native Microsoft Application Look

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, installation

I've seen software (not developed by Microsoft) that look exactly as Microsoft Office or their installation look exactly the same as installing Visual Studio. My question is that, is such look and style already included as a project type in Visual Studio 2013 (if so how can it be used), or what third party frameworks can be used for doing so.

I have already tried Telerik Components for WPF, they do have some themes but none would completely look like the ones I explained.

Comment: Related if it is going about installators: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233642/how-do-you-make-a-really-nice-installer-like-visual-studios

Comment: Please note that that the `look` you are after may not be available in the default UX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. There is no such template included in Visual Studio. You have to implement such design yourself.

Though there are third party controls available which you can use. I used [Mahapps.metro](http://mahapps.com/) which is close enough. You can create their `MetroWindow`, hide its `TitleBar` and use [WindowCammands](http://mahapps.com/guides/quick-start.html#windowcommands) to add buttons like 'Feedback', 'Help' etc.

You can find more such third-party controls if you search for "Metro Controls".
This should be a good start for you.

Comment: Thanks but that is not even close to what I'm looking for. Office look is not Metro Style, and looking for Metro Style theme is going off course.

Comment: Please post screen shot of what exactly you are trying to achieve.